# How to display a collection of collection of components with React dealing with key properties?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I want to display an array of array of logs:

```
export interface IResult {
  succeeded: boolean;
  logs: IServerLogs;
}

export interface IServerLogs {
    step1: ILog[],
    step2: ILog[],
    step3: ILog[]
}

export interface ILog {
  id: number;
  date: Date;
  msg: string;
  severity: number;
  obj?: any;
}
```

I have an array of IResult in App.tsx

```
render() {
    return (
    {this.state.results.map((result, index) => (
      <Results key={index} results={result} index={index + 1} />
    ))}
   )
```

}

In results.tsx:

```
render() {
    const { step1, step2, step3 } = this.props.results.logs;
    const { index } = this.props;
    return (
     <div>
            <div>
                #{index} Status: {this.props.results.ret ? "SUCCEEDED" : "FAILED"}
                <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faWindowClose} />
            </div>
            <Accordion>
                { step1.length > 0 && <Result logs={step1}  title="Step 1" /> }
                { step2.length> 0 && <Result logs={step2} title="Step 2" /> }
                { step3.length > 0 && <Result logs={step3}  title="Step 3" /> }
            </Accordion>
        </div>
   )
```

}

In result.tsx:

```
render() {
    const { logs, title } = this.props;
    return (
        <AccordionItem>
            <AccordionItemTitle><b>{title}</b></AccordionItemTitle>
            <AccordionItemBody>
                <Table striped bordered hover size="sm">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Date</th>
                        <th>Message</th>
                        <th>Obj</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                {
                    logs.map((log, index) =>
                    (
                        <tr key={log.id} style={{ color: log.severity == 0 ? "green": "red"}}>
                            <td key={index+1+log.id}>{moment(log.date).format("HH:mm:ss")}</td>
                            <td key={index+2+log.id}>{log.msg}</td>
                            <td key={index+3+log.id}>{log.obj}</td>
                        </tr>
                    ))
                }
                </tbody>
            </Table>
            </AccordionItemBody>
        </AccordionItem>
    );
}
```

And with all this stuff I get the following error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
    in td (created by Result)
    in tr (created by Result)
    in tbody (created by Result)
    in table (created by Table)
```

I tried setting and removing keys here and there but I always get the same error message, on TRs or TDs...

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: What does `log.obj` contain? Is it another object? You can try to render `{JSON.stringify(log.obj)}` and see if that gets rid of the error, so you know where to look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see

```
export interface ILog {
  id: number;
  date: Date;
  msg: string;
  severity: number;
  obj?: any;
}
```

has obj type as any. So if the ILog.obj is an object, it cant be render. So you might need to add a check if its an object render a property of the object other wise render obj.

Comment: I deleted the obj property of all the ILog objects in the arrays (and I don't render the property anymore), and I still get the error :/

Comment: Umm can you add your latest code in jsfiddle or codepen?

Comment: I inspected more deeply my ILog objects and it turns out that the last log had an object in the msg property...due to a misuse of typing in a try...catch on the server side...thank you!